# What is kdmflush?

Tags: kernel, ps

I've entered `ps -aux` and found this `kdmflush` process.

```
root       274  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   06:50   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       321  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   06:50   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       328  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   06:50   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       798  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   06:50   0:00 [kdmflush]
```

I can't find any documentation online relating to this process. Does anyone know what this process is?

Answer (score 4):

It is a kernel thread.

`kdmflush` is used by [Device Mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_mapper) to process deferred work that it has queued up from other contexts where doing immediately so would be problematic.

[See line 1759](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/md/dm.c?id=HEAD).